# How to change the default file type Windows saves ripped audio as?

Tags: windows-7, audio, windows-media-player, file-types

When ripping audio files from a CD onto your computer, Windows 7 automatically saves them as .wma (Windows Media Audio) files. But some applications can't play WMA files, so I was wondering if it is possible to automatically have Windows save them as a different file type (such as MP3)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use CDEX http://cdex.mu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: [Some songs don't show up in Google Play Music on phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132190/some-songs-dont-show-up-in-google-play-music-on-phone)

> Windows Media Player has a way to change the default *Media Rip
>   format*:
>
> 1. Go to `Organize`->`Options`
> 2. Switch to the `Rip CD` tab
> 3. Select the format you'd like from the drop-down list.
> 4. Select your preferred quality setting.
> 5. Hit *`OK`*

Comment: @RogUE for me it says (translated from German) "copy music"

Comment: Actually I don't have a "Copy Music" tab but I have a "Rip CD" tab that had the same option.